# Custom component in ionic v3

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I wanted to create a simple component and include it on a page. I created it with `ionic g component my-header` (ionic-cli v3 beta), fixed the IonicPageModule bug and then added  to another page. I then get this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'my-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'my-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'my-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

The "MyHeaderComponent" was added to the @NgModule declarations automatically.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

The component is located inside my `components` folder:

components/my-header/my-header.html

```
<div>
  {{text}}
</div>
```

components/my-header/my-header.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyHeaderComponent } from './my-header';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyHeaderComponent,
   ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    MyHeaderComponent
  ],
  entryComponents:[
    MyHeaderComponent
  ]
})
export class MyHeaderComponentModule {}
```

components/my-header/my-header.scss

```
my-header {}
```

components/my-header/my-header.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-header',
  templateUrl: 'my-header.html'
})
export class MyHeaderComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello MyHeaderComponent Component');
     this.text = 'Hello World';
  }

}
```

app/app.module.ts

```
/* imports */
import { MyHeaderComponent } from '../components/my-header/my-header';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    MyHeaderComponent
  ],
...
```

pages/home/home.html

Comment: do you have a separate module.ts file for your component?

Comment: Yes, I added the whole code relevant to the component

Comment: Don't think this is an answer or that it deserves a new question, but I came here because my lazy-loaded page got this error.  Along with the accepted answer of importing the `ComponentsModule` into the page module, I had to add the component to `entryComponents`  of the components module (which is shown in the question).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You dont have to import `MyHeaderComponent` in ngModule.

You should import `MyHeaderComponentModule` in your page module  where you want to use this.

```
 imports: [
    MyHeaderComponentModule,
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about importing it in the page module `home.module.ts` directly. For some reason it doesn't work if I import it in my `app.module.ts`. I tried that before because I thought that would make it available "gobally".

Comment: for Ionic 3 don't put in imports but in declarations of your page module.

Comment: @ZeeshanAnjum modules go in imports.  page/component go in declaration

Answer (score 31):

Since ionic 3 supports lazy-loading, you need not import your custom component in the app. module.ts file. Instead you can import it in specific page's module.ts file. For eg: If you want to use your custom component in your homepage you can just import it in your home.module.ts file as given below:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';
import { MyHeaderComponent }from '../../components/myheader/myheader';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage,
    MyHeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
   
  ],
  exports: [
    HomePage,
  ]
})
export class HomePageModule {
 
}
```

However don't forget to remove your import and declarations from app.module.ts file which is added automatically when you create your custom component.

Comment: I my opinion you have to move `MyHeaderComponent` from `declarations` to `imports` otherwise it will not work

Comment: @Sid Puttur Can you help?I want to use a component (UserCardComponent) in 2 or more pages. I declared the component in my HomePage module and was able to use it fine but when I tried to declare it in another module I get error "Type UserCardComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: HomePageModule and ContactsPageModule! Please consider moving UserCardComponent to a higher module that imports HomePageModule and ContactsPageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes UserCardComponent then import that NgModule in HomePageModule and ContactsPageModule."

Answer (score 2):

*Late answer for the thread, but I'm sure there's more people that can use this information explained in another perspective.*

In Ionic, custom angular components are organized under a separate module called `ComponentsModule`. When the first component is generated using `ionic generate component`, along with the component, ionic generates the `ComponentsModule`. Any subsequent components gets added to the same module, rightly so.

Here's a sample `ComponentsModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomAngularComponent } from './custom/custom-angular-component';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [CustomAngularComponent],
    imports: [IonicModule],
    exports: [CustomAngularComponent],
    entryComponents:[

      ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

To use the `ComponentsModule` in the app, like any other angular modules, the `ComponentsModules` needs to be imported to the `AppModule`. ionic generate component (v 4.12) does not add this step, so this has to be added manually.

Excerpt of AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //declaration
  ],
  imports: [
    //other modules 
    ComponentsModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    //ionic pages
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    //other providers
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Logically it should be working, but it is still not working. I ran ionic g component custom-angular-component and then followed the same, but still, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You must import component in the module. Make sure you also export that component.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        IonicModule,
    ],
    declarations:[
        MyHeaderComponent
    ],
    exports:[
        MyHeaderComponent
    ],
    entryComponents:[
        MyHeaderComponent
    ]

})
```

Comment: Sadly that still doesn't work for me. I updated my question to include code samples.

Comment: That didn't work either... I fixed it using suraj's answer, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my module. Hope it will help you answer your question:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TestPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(TestPage),
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
    PipesModule,
    NavigatorComponentModule
  ],
  exports: [
    EntriesPage,
  ],
  providers:[
    NavigatorComponent
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify: I am using the a custom navigatorComponent in many pages (reusable component).

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { PipesModule } from '../../pipes/PipesModule';
import { NavigatorComponent } from '../../components/navigator/navigator';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module';
import { NavigatorComponentModule } from '../../components/navigator/navigator.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TestPage,

  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(EntriesPage),
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
    PipesModule,
    NavigatorComponentModule

  ],
  exports: [
   TestPage,

  ],
  providers:[
    NavigatorComponent
  ]
})
export class TestPageModule {}
```

Note: the navigatorComponent has 4 files: the ts, css, html and yourcomponentname.module.ts. The "ionic g component " command doesn't generate the last file (yourcomponentname.module.ts). So I did it.

Comment: ionic g component generates "components.module.ts" that is one module to include all the components in ionic. That module should be included in the NgModule imports.