# I'm trying to declare a custom component to use in two different pages (of my ionic app) but getting an error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, components

I'm trying to use a custom component called UserCardComponent in two different pages in my ionic v3 app.

I followed this answer (the one with 26 votes) which says to declare custom components in "a specific page's module.ts file". [Custom component in ionic v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507800/custom-component-in-ionic-v3?rq=1)
So I firstly declared the component in my HomePageModule and was able to use it fine within the home.html.

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';
import { UserCardComponent } from '../../components/user-card/user-card';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage,
    UserCardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage)
  ],
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

I then tried to declare it (in the same way) in ContactsPageModule to use in contacts.html however I get the following error:

```
Type UserCardComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: HomePageModule and ContactsPageModule! 
Please consider moving UserCardComponent to a higher module that imports HomePageModule and ContactsPageModule. 
You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes UserCardComponent then import that NgModule in HomePageModule and ContactsPageModule
```

When I try to just declare the UserCardComponent in the app.module.ts file I get a Template parse error and the custom component won't work in any pages.

Can you advise me on what to do?  The error says to move the "UserCardComponent to a higher module that imports HomePageModule and ContactsPageModule. "
Can you tell me how I would do this? I'm new to ionic. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare the `UserCardComponent` in the `HomePageModule`, you only need to import the `HomePageModule` in the `ContactsPageModule` but it introduces dirty dependency between theses modules.

A better way is to declare `UserCardComponent` in a specific module `UserCardModule` and then to import this specific module in `HomePageModule` and in `ContactsPageModule`.

**user-card.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UserCardComponent } from './user-card';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UserCardComponent
  ]
})
export class UserCardModule {}
```

**home.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';
import { UserCardModule } from '../../components/user-card/user-card.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
    UserCardModule
  ],
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you so much :) However the folder structure is slightly different to your answer... In user-card.module.ts it should be import { UserCardComponent } from './user-card'; and in home.module.ts the line should be import { UserCardModule } from '../../components/user-card/user-card.module'; ...if you can change that i'll mark the answer correct. If you want maybe i could edit your answer?

Comment: I had the same issue (Angular 13, Ionic v6) and the solution wasn't working for me. When I tried to display the component in a template I got `'app-usercard' is not a known element`, unless I added the component to the `user-card.module.ts` export: `@NgModule({ [...] exports: [ UserCardComponent ], [...] })`